# How to run flask application on https using apache?

Tags: python, apache, flask, ssl, vps

I want to run a simple flask application on https. So here are the things i already done:

1. First of all i wrote a simple Flask app
2. Then i've run it using mod_wsgi for apache
3. Then i made a self-signed cert and applied it to my apache server.
   And the problem that when i try to get to my application this way: http://example.com/ i see the result of my flask app, but when i try https://example.com/ i see apache 'default welcome page'.
   Actually i understand that i should edit something in apache's configs, but i dont know what exactly.
   P.S. self-signed cert works properly

Comment: This question should at-least include your config for anyone to help, however I suggest taking a look at [Mozilla's secure config generator](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=apache&version=2.4.41&config=intermediate&openssl=1.1.1k&guideline=5.6) which includes a config which redirects HTTP requests to the HTTPS endpoint.  This is probably the best starting point.